# Is there a way to display the x,y,z axis and change the names in vpython?

Tags: vpython

I want to display the x,y,z axis with another name (x1,x2,x3) in a 3d vpython figure. Is there a way to do this besides defining 3 arrows?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "the x,y,z axis"? I may not be answering your question. If x1 is a scalar, and x2 is a scalar, and x3 is a scalar, of course you can create a vector v = vector(x1,x2,x3) or v = vec(x1,x2,x3). (vec is a synonym for vector.)